# Can FP read scientific notation?

Tags: fp, floating-point

I'm reading numbers from a file that are in scientific notation, and I'd like to do a simple calculation with them using FP. However, it's giving me the error `FP error: Illegal character e found in float number`.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}

\FPeval{\x}{1e-20}
\x

\end{document}
```

Can FP parse scientific notation? Is there another package that I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `xfp` (which uses the LaTeX3 FPU):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\edef\x{\fpeval{1e-20}}
\x

\end{document}
```

Comment: But not uppercase `E`: `Unknown fp word E.` ><